# How a web development production process should work?

Tags: development-environment

I'm reaching out in the hopes that some of my fellow developers can help provide sources/workflow diagrams/explanations/etc. of how a proper web development environment should/could work today.

Currently, I work for an organization that allows content editors full access to the production server, granting them the possibility of pushing content and page creations to the live server with the click of the button.

In the past, I'm used to a bare minimum 3 step process (development -> staging -> production). The access to these different branches are controlled by server administrators and permission to "push" assets from one environment to another is strictly controlled by server administrators/web administrators.

Our current system allows anyone with general access to gain control of document creation/content manipulation without any restrictions (besides global assets changes [css/javascript/templates/etc.]). This results in unexperienced web authors not following brand guidelines, discovering their "creative" side and breaking page formatting due to no limitations, absolutely no tracking of what is being edited and pushed "live" as well as the typical "this page I created is broken and is currently live, we need it fixed asap" discussion.

Our website consists of 50,000+ individual pages (a large portion outdated) and over 30 web authors. Would it be more difficult to retrain our current web authors to use a system we actually have built to follow a standard, or, would it be easier for us to allow them to continue working in the same fashion and relying on our administrators to constantly fix issues that actively exist on our live domain?

Also, would any of you have some clear documentation on processes with any time of data showing that following a development process for a website is better than allowing everyone access to a single server?

So far, from my research, I'm finding a lot of outdated discussions that may be looked at different if it was something a bit more recent. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm trying to put together a push to improve our overall process and limit the amount of fixes having to be done on our active production server.

Thanks!

FYI - Our current CMS is "TeamSite" and we actively have 3 servers with different content/assets due to not having a solid process in place.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a permission issue at all. Even me, who work only locally on some project, I never put my scripts in others before I test them first, and I have separate folder for that. But however, all you need, is space for testing scripts, but, also, permissions are not issue there, but however, look to make some restrictions, it is not very best practice, for servers, to be completely opened.

Answer (score 0):

Altova has XML spy which is an editor that helps find 'broken' pieces in XML based formatting by not letting you save changes without prompting that something is missing. Depending on the content your users are publishing, you might look at some other 'proofing' software that might be out there.

I'm not sure what you can arrange to make an IIS-based 'localhost' replication of your pages. End users can save new content and test against that platform instead of updating live content without testing first. This is simply additional content that the first user input about testing, but that seems like a viable solution for training your editors not to be foolish.